# How to handle synonymous tag groupings?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

What should be done about synonymous or partially-synonymous *combinations of tags*, where the tags have distinct meanings when used individually?

For example, right now:

- [c-preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-preprocessor) has 574 questions
- [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) + [preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preprocessor) has 955 questions (84 also tagged with [c-preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-preprocessor))
- [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) + [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) has 1440 questions (94 also tagged with [c-preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-preprocessor))

It's almost certain that the vast majority of these questions are about the same basic subject, so that's some significant dilution-of-meaning across different tag sets. But the three tags people are using are in no way remotely synonymous when taken on their own; e.g. the vast majority of "macros" questions are about Excel or VBA, nothing at all to do with C.

(This is the only topic where I've noticed the issue, but I don't follow very many tags. I don't know how relevant it could be on a wider scale.)

This particular niche topic presumably doesn't justify the upheaval of mass-editing, but in the general case, what can/should be done about this? Or is it simply not a problem beyond being a minor nuisance to the very obsessive?

If it's worthy of a feature request, I would wonder if it's possible for synonymous combinations to be recognised by the tagging system automatically and e.g. have a popup suggest a different option on the Ask page.

Comment: The only thing on the last 2 pages of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+macros?&sort=newest&pagesize=50) which is not about the c-preprocessor: http://stackoverflow.com/q/692382 Still, there are 27 more pages to go. (And the same for [tag:c]+[tag:preprocessor]-[tag:macros])

Answer (score 2):

That [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) may have merit (feel free to post it separately), but I feel that in general, this is not a *huge* problem. They can be retagged as you come across them if you wish, but the general meaning comes across either way.

As for the ones tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preprocessor), *and* [c-preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-preprocessor), something needs to be done there: that's useless tagging (the same thing is being said twice). The only reason I can see for doing that is maybe for reaching a wider audience. In that case, it might be better to leave [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c-preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-preprocessor), but [preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preprocessor) isn't really needed in that case. I have retagged and cleaned up these questions accordingly.

Comment: Seems to me that *two* things are being said twice, and the least-redundant subset would be `[c]` and `[preprocessor]`.

Comment: @AirThomas Then would it be better to burninate [tag:c-preprovessor]?

Comment: I don't have a strong feeling either way; just making an observation, and wondering if you had another reason for choosing the pair you did that's not explained in your answer.

Comment: @AirThomas I picked [tag:c] for the audience and [tag:c-preprocessor] for the specific topic. That said, I'm not entirely sure why [tag:c-preprocessor] exists in the first place if you could combine tags, but we might as well use it since it already exists.

Comment: @AstroCB `c-preprocessor` definitely shouldn't get burned - it's a standalone language that (technically) doesn't need to involve C, so it has a justified independent existence. Correspondingly for questions that *are* tagged `c`, I'd say the difference between the two tags is akin to the difference between e.g. `compiler` and `gcc`.

Comment: @Leushenko Then in that case, I'd say the choice to leave [tag:c] and [tag:c-preprocessor] together is probably best.